# Conditional Block in word Aspose (<<if [var] )

Tags: java, aspose.words

I'm creating a word document using mailmerge in word and I need to show a block of word depending on a conditional var:

```
<<if [var]>>
show text
<</if>>
```

I'm build the json object to pass a word document in java like:

```
InputStream targetStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(object).getBytes());
            JsonDataSource ds = new JsonDataSource(targetStream);
            ReportingEngine engine = new ReportingEngine();
            engine.setOptions(ReportBuildOptions.ALLOW_MISSING_MEMBERS);
            engine.buildReport(docIstanza, ds, "obj");
            docIstanza.getMailMerge().setFieldMergingCallback(new HandleFieldMerging());
```

I have a problem to understand how to use the if instruction in word document. The var is a Boolean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Mail Merge](https://docs.aspose.com/words/java/mail-merge-and-reporting/) and [LINQ Reporting Engine](https://docs.aspose.com/words/java/linq-reporting-engine/) are two different ways to fill the template with data. If you use LINQ Reporting Engine, then in your template you should simply put the condition as regular text.
https://docs.aspose.com/words/net/using-conditional-blocks/

If you use Mail Merge feature, you should use MS Word MergeFields
https://docs.aspose.com/words/java/mail-merge-template/
in this case to show conditional content, you should use IF fields.

In your case you get data from JSON and value of `var` variable is nullable Boolean. In this case you have to use `<<if [var == true]>>`

Comment: Hi @Alexey thanks for your help,  I my case I resolved with <<if [var == true]>> where var is a Boolean type java. It is a corret way?

Comment: In your case you get data from JSON and value of `var` variable is nullable Boolean. In this case you have to use `<<if [var == true]>>`. I updated my answer accordingly.